# Как написать регулярное выражение, чтобы оно пропускало только числа, в т.ч. с точкой и запятой?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно при вводе отсекать все не цифры. Сделано сейчас так

```
elem.onkeyup = function () {
  this.value = this.value.replace(',', ".");
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, "");
```

Но пользователь может ввести что-то вроде `9.34.`

То есть нужно задействовать регулярку вида `9.9` где 9 - любое целое число

ответом ставить не буду. но вот так вроде проще

```
elem.on('blur', function () {
 var value = this.value.split('.');
        if (isNumeric(value[1])) this.value = value[0]+'.'+value[1];
        else this.value = value[0];
```

Comment: в общем и в целом да.

Comment: Я так понимаю, нужно чтобы проходили целые числа и десятичные дроби? 9.,.123,.900 - такое же не стоит пропускать, верно?
Тогда логичнее воспользоваться например такой конструкцией:

var str = '0.756';
var result =  isNaN(str);

Comment: if (isNaN(this.value)) { // введено не число
                                    // показать ошибку

Comment: жестко ограничить ввод хочу. оно надежнее смотрится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо следить за изменением поля, и валидировать его значение при каждом изменении:

```
var $el = $('#sometext')
    ,prev = $el.val() // предыдущее, заведомо правильное значение
    ,filterValue = function(i,v) {
        v = v.replace(',','.');  // меняем запятую на точку если надо (?)
        // с начала строки несколько или ноль цифр подряд,
        // потом точка или запятая один или ноль раз
        // потом несколько или ноль цифр подряд до конца строки
        // если ок, в prev очередное правильное значение
        if(v.match(/^\d*[\.,]?\d*$/)) return prev = v;
        else return prev; // если пришло не правильное значение – ставим предыдущее, правильное
    }

    ,handleChange = function(e) { // слушаем любые изменения поля
        $el.val(filterValue);
    }
;

$el.on('input', handleChange);
```

[Рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/Lv2yg5gp/) – можно и вставлять copy-paste'ом, и работают кнопки backspace, del и стрелки. И много точек не пройдёт. Хотя, если вам нужны разделители тысяч – не пройдёт: `1,000,000.22` – нужно уточнять, какие форматы допустимы.

---

**[На чистом JS](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/Lv2yg5gp/6/):**

```
var el = document.getElementById('sometext')
    ,prev = el.value
    ,filterValue = function(e) {
        var v = el.value.replace(',','.');
        el.value = v.match(/^\d*[\.,]?\d*$/) ? prev = v : prev;
    }
;

el.addEventListener('input', filterValue, false);
```

Comment: а на чистом можно написать? а то jquery символы | в имени элемента не понимает

Comment: Сами не справитесь? Можно двумя обратными слэшами отквотить символ pipe ("|"): `$('#invalid_\\|_id`)`

Comment: добавил на чистом JS

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать что-то такое:

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '#sometext', function(e) {
 var arr = this.value.replace(',', '.').replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, "").split('.');
  if (arr.length > 1 && arr[0].length) arr[0]+='.';
    //console.log(arr);
    this.value = arr.join('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="sometext" />
```

Comment: правая кнопка мыши - вставить

Comment: @xaja, и что не так?

Comment: ну, все что угодно можно запихать в `input`

Comment: @xaja, ну так повесьте этот код на нужные события и живите спокойно :Р `onkeyup` использует ТС в своем вопросе, но ни кто не мешает использовать другое событие.